# Get session data within an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This could be an incredibly stupid question. I'm good at certain things in PHP, but being entirely self-taught, I missed some of the basics. This is also my first CodeIgniter project so I don't know any of the helpful shortcuts it provides.

I can't seem to find information on this anywhere because I don't know what terms to search for. It's probably a pretty simple solution so bear with me.

I'm setting up an ACP and I'd like to display a list of current user sessions on the "dashboard". I'm calling this directly from the database because it's the only way I know how:

```
<?php    
  $session = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ci_sessions` ORDER BY `last_activity` ASC LIMIT 0, 30 ");
  $session_array = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($session)) {$session_array[] = $row;}
  foreach ($session_array as $data):?>
  <li><?=$data['ip_address']?> [<?=$data['user_agent']?>]<br /><?=$data['user_data']?></li>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Unfortunately, this is what I get for the $data['user_data'] part and I have no idea to parse it for the data I want:

```
a:6:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:8:"identity";s:16:"email@email.com";s:8:"username";s:11:"first last";s:5:"email";s:16:"email@email.com";s:7:"user_id";s:1:"2";s:14:"old_last_login";s:10:"1358653607";}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Check the [**`unserialize()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function.

Comment: Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"

Comment: My bad. I'm new. Forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

That data is serialized. Just use [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to turn it into an array.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, thanks John. Due to my inexperience, however, I hit another small roadblock: I tried storing the unserialized version of this data as a variable, but if I var_dump or echo any part of the array, I just get "resource(60) of type (mysql result)" or "Resource id #60", respectively.